# Convert date time string like Joda DateTime(String) with Java 8

Tags: java, datetime, time, jodatime

I have an API that can return date values in JSON in three possible formats:

1. 2017-04-30T00:00+02:00
2. 2016-12-05T04:00
3. 2016-12-05

I need to convert all three into a `java.time.LocalTimeDate`. Joda has a nice constructor on the `DateTime` object which takes in all three formats as Strings and converts them. `DateTime dt = new DateTime(StringFromAPI);` is enough.

Is there a similar capability in Java 8 (`java.time` package)? It seems I now first have to regex the `String` to check the format, then create either a `LocalDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime` or `LocalDate` and convert the latter 2. to `LocalDateTime`. Seems a bit cumbersome to me. Is there a easy way?

Comment: Read about [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: So the `+02:00` in the first format should just be ignored? Are you assuming time 0:00 (midnight) in the third?

Comment: @OleV.V. yes and yes.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. In that case I have guessed correctly and stand by my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I am presenting two options, each with its pros and cons.

One, build a custom `DateTimeFormatter` to accept your three possible formats:

```
public static LocalDateTime parse(String dateFromJson) {
    DateTimeFormatter format = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
            .optionalStart()
            .appendLiteral('T')
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
            .optionalStart()
            .appendOffsetId()
            .optionalEnd()
            .optionalEnd()
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
            .toFormatter();
    return LocalDateTime.parse(dateFromJson, format);
}
```

On one hand, it’s clean, on the other, someone could easily find it a bit tricky. For the three sample strings in your question it produces:

```
2017-04-30T00:00
2016-12-05T04:00
2016-12-05T00:00
```

The other option, try the three different formats in turn and pick the one that works:

```
public static LocalDateTime parse(String dateFromJson) {
    try {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(dateFromJson);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        // ignore, try next format
    }
    try {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(dateFromJson, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        // ignore, try next format
    }
    return LocalDate.parse(dateFromJson).atStartOfDay();
}
```

I don’t consider this the most beautiful code, still some may think it’s more straightforward than the first option? I think there’s a quality in relying on the built-in ISO formats alone. The results for your three sample strings are the same as above.

Comment: Excuse my curiosity, @BartKooijman, could you use my answer? Though I put an effort in it, I realize I’m not giving you anything as simple as you describe the JodaTime `DateTime` constructor. I am not so much asking for an accept tick mark as for your general and honest reaction/feedback.