# How do I create default a ZonedDateTime to midnight if HH:mm:ss is not defined?

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
public ZonedDateTime getZdt(String myDate, String format) {
    return  ZonedDateTime.parse(
                myDate,   
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format)
                    .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            );
}

getZdt("17-05-2017 00:10:59", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") //works fine
getZdt("17-05-2017", "dd-MM-yyyy") //DateTimeParseException (...Unable to obtain LocalTime from TemporalAccessor:)
```

What I'm trying to do is pretty simple. How do I get this to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert date time string like Joda DateTime(String) with Java 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43208870/convert-date-time-string-like-joda-datetimestring-with-java-8) (with a little abstraction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got three suggestions for you.

First, does that have to be the same method? Could you have two? I am assuming you have got only two possible formats; if you have ten, it’s a different story I think.

```
/** gets a ZonedDateTime from a date string with no time information */
public ZonedDateTime getZdtFromDateString(String myDate, String format) {
    return LocalDate.parse(myDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format))
            .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault());
}
```

You may of course leave out the `format` parameter and have the format be constant.

Of course you can get what you want from a single method. Rather than passing the format to the method, I suggest your method detects it itself.

One option is a custom `DateTimeFormatter` that handles both formats:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter format = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("dd-MM-uuuu")
        .optionalStart()
        .appendPattern(" HH:mm:ss")
        .optionalEnd()
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
        .toFormatter();

public ZonedDateTime getZdt(String myDate) {
    return LocalDateTime.parse(myDate, format).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
}
```

Finally, [Jacob G.’s idea of trying both](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44037267/5772882) is not too bad. Here’s my version:

```
public ZonedDateTime getZdt(String myDate, String format) {
    try {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(myDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format))
                .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
        return LocalDate.parse(myDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format))
                .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    }
}
```

Again, one might prefer to leave out the `format` parameter and use two constant formats.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be to change your method to the following:

```
public ZonedDateTime getZdt(String myDate, String format) {
    try {
        return ZonedDateTime.parse(myDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format).withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
    } catch (DateTimeException e) {
        return ZonedDateTime.parse(myDate + " 00:00:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format + " HH:mm:ss").withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
    }
}
```

This assumes that a `DateTimeException` would only be thrown if `format` did not suffice.  However, I think it would be better for you to make you own `Exception` in this case, but this would work.

I'd like to see if anyone else has an easier method of handling this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse a `LocalDate` first, then you can convert that to a `ZonedDateTime`:

```
LocalDate.parse("17-05-2017", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"))
        .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault())
```