# Selecting Date format based on the string

Tags: java, datetime, date-format, date

I have class which receives Date in string format from other class. It is now receiving two different formats

Format 1: YYYY_MM_DD

Format 2: EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy

now I want to write a method which receives this string and convert it into required format like this 'DDMMMYYYY '

Comment: Do you mean a method that can handle format1 and format2 and then result to DDMMMYYYY??

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Yes , exactly

Comment: I would prefer to use two `DateTimeFormatter` objects. Try parsing into a `LocalDate` with one of them, if that throws a `DateTimeParseException`, then do it with the other one. Finally format into the desired format using a third one. Remember: Year is lowercase `yyyy` or `uuuu`, day of month is lowercase `dd`. And give your formatters appropriate locale.

Comment: I agree that this question is a duplicate. How to parse a date from a string that may come in two or three different formats has been asked an answered more than once before. I beg to differ about which question this one is a duplicate of.

Comment: Example of a similar question: [Convert date time string like Joda DateTime(String) with Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43208870/convert-date-time-string-like-joda-datetimestring-with-java-8).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try brute force to parse catching the exceptions:

## edit:

using the java8 API (adapt the format as you need/want)

```
public   String convertDateFormatJ8(String format) {
    String retFormat = "ddMMyyy";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[yyyy_dd_MM][yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm]");
    try {
        LocalDateTime localDate = LocalDateTime.parse(format, formatter);
        return localDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(retFormat));
    } catch (DateTimeParseException ex) {
        System.err.println("impossible to parse to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    }
    try {
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(format, formatter);
        return localDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(retFormat));
    } catch (DateTimeParseException ex) {
        System.err.println("impossible to parse to yyyy_dd_MM");
    }

    return null;

}
```

---

for old java versions

```
public String convertDateFormat(String format) {
        DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY_MM_DD");
        DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
        DateFormat dfResult = new SimpleDateFormat("DDMMMYYYY ");
        Date d = null;
        try {
            d = df1.parse(format);
            return dfResult.format(d);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.err.println("impossible to parse to " + "YYYY_MM_DD");
        }
        try {
            d = df2.parse(format);
            return dfResult.format(d);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.err.println("impossible to parse to " + "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

if you give any other invalid string, the string returned will be null!

Comment: you miss the third DateFormat converting the Date to a String like DDMMMYYYY ;-)

Comment: Holy pattern, Thanks!!

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the outdated `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. Today we have so much better. See for example [Andriy Rymar’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44302191/5772882).

Answer (score 3):

You can use this approach and declare optional section in pattern :

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[yyyy_MM_dd][EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy]", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

This `formatter` will parse date for both patterns and then you can easily convert it to required format.

P.S. I've tested it but not sure which date should be parsable for `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy` template. So just play with it and use Java 8 approaches (Java Time)

Comment: [Here is](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) explanation how to play with it.

Comment: In a format pattern string the first format should be written as yyyy_MM_dd, with lowercase y and d (capital Y is for weekbased year, only useful with week number; capital D for day of year).

Comment: @AndriyRymar As Ole V.V. commented, your code in this Answer is *very* broken. Please fix or delete.

Comment: @OleV.V. , yeah, sorry for that, I just user format from question, and there are capital letters. My Point is to use Java 8 approaches with optional section in pattern. It would decrease code complexity and become general approach.

Comment: @BasilBourque, fixed, thank you.