# How to convert date in string with or without time into DATE

Tags: java, sql, date, datetime

I have a date in string format like "2017-11-16" or "2017-11-16 12:59:11.243". I have to convert it to Date.

Below is my code:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss");
Date createdOn = formatter.parse(date);
```

It works fine when the date is "2017-11-16 12:59:11.243". But not able to format with "2017-11-16" date.

String date is coming from URL, so it could be either with time or without time. How can I convert it into Date in spite of the fact what type of date is coming from URL?

Actually, I have to find row from the database based on the date. In the database, the date is storing in the format like 2017-11-16 12:59:11.243. But If from URL 2017-11-16 is coming then it should find according to this date.

Comment: Parse the date+time format and when failing parse date format. _One could parse the date with a position in the string, and then parse the time only from that position, but that is more complex._

Comment: It wasn’t what you asked about: `ss.sss` for seconds with decimals will give you a wrong result. Use `ss.SSS` with uppercase `SSS` for milliseconds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert date time string like Joda DateTime(String) with Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43208870/convert-date-time-string-like-joda-datetimestring-with-java-8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the pars based on the presence of time,

```
if(dateOrDataTime.contains(":")){
  //Use parser with date-time. & fetch with equal
}else{
  //Use parser for date only. & fetch using date(date_time)
}
```

Comment: Thanks . I did like this now.

Comment: Easy, it’s common practice to mark as accepted after a couple of days to invite other suggestions in before doing that. Questions with an accepted answer tend to get less attention.